# Is SQL (using LookML) able to LEFT JOIN multiple tables (4) based on a Date Field?

Tags: sql, data-visualization, looker

I am currently developing a LookML Explore Model that LEFT JOINs 4 tables each with PK of PID. The grain of the data is different between the 4 tables and it is causing issues of duplication and incorrectly high Count totals.

Is there a way to LEFT JOIN on a Date column between the 4 tables by using a DIMDATE table set up in our warehouse?

Here is the current Explore LookML:

```
 ### SMS ####################
explore: stg_mysql_twiliooutboundsms {
  group_label: "Usage"
  label: "SMS"

  join: dimaccount {
    sql_on: ${dimaccount.pid} = ${stg_mysql_twiliooutboundsms.pid};;
    type: left_outer
    relationship: many_to_one
  }

  join: stg_mysql_twilioinboundsms {
    sql_on: ${stg_mysql_twiliooutboundsms.pid} = ${stg_mysql_twilioinboundsms.pid} ;;
    type: left_outer
    relationship: one_to_one
  }

  join: stg_mysql_telnyxoutboundsms {
    sql_on: ${stg_mysql_twiliooutboundsms.pid} = ${stg_mysql_telnyxoutboundsms.pid} ;;
    type: left_outer
    relationship: one_to_one
  }

  join: stg_mysql_telnyxinboundsms {
    sql_on: ${stg_mysql_twiliooutboundsms.pid} = ${stg_mysql_telnyxinboundsms.pid}  ;;
    type: left_outer
    relationship: one_to_one
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data and DDLs

Comment: I do not have any DDL available. However, Here are the fields of the 5 different tables: Table 1: id pid member_id contact_id from to message message_sid messaging_service_sid segments price tms_sent tms_updated message_status
Table 2: id pid member_id patient_id from to message telnyx_id tms_sent tms_updated api_status delivery_status
Table 3: id pid tms from to message_sid message
Table 4: id pid from to message telnyx_id tms
Table 5 (to normalize using DIMDATE): Date Year Quarter Month MonthName DayOfMonth WeekOfMonth DayName DayOfWeek DayType BeginDST EndDST

Comment: I should be able to JOIN on PID, but the grain of the table is causing redundancy therefore inaccurate counts when pulled into Looker via the Explore.

Comment: Some sample data would help.

Comment: I figured it out, thank you.

Comment: Good to know. The sample data helps understand what are we trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could join all your tables onto a table which is one row per date.
However, the issue is down to asymmetric aggregation. Looker should deal with this correctly by accounting for the repeated rows, using a MD5 hash function in the SQL. if it is not, its because either

1. your primary keys are incorrect
2. your join logic is wrong (relationships most likely).

Please check the above two first.